# A Matrix Norm Inequality $\|A^{1/2}B^{1/2}(A+B)^{-1/2}\|_F \geq \|A^{1/2}(A+B)^{-1/2}B^{1/2}\|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $\|X\|_F:= \sqrt{\text{Tr} \left(XX^\dagger\right) }$ denote the Frobenius norm.
Does anyone know how to show the norm inequality:

> $\left\|A^{\frac12}B^{\frac12}(A+B)^{-\frac12}\right\|_F \geq 
>  \left\|A^{\frac12}(A+B)^{-\frac12}B^{\frac12}\right\|_F$

for any positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$ ? We have numerical evidence for this inequality to be true.

The inequality obviously does not hold if we replace $(A+B)^{-\frac12}$ by arbitrary positive definite matrix $Z$, i.e.
$\left\|A^{\frac12}B^{\frac12}Z\right\|_F \geq 
\left\|A^{\frac12}ZB^{\frac12}\right\|_F$. Hence, it seems that the sum $(A+B)$ admits some nice structures to ensure the norm inequality.

Actually, we expect that the inequality:

> $\left\|A^{\frac12}B^{\frac12}(A+B)^{-1}B^{\frac12}A^{\frac12}\right\|
>  \geq
>  \left\|A^{\frac12}(A+B)^{-\frac12}B(A+B)^{-\frac12}A^{\frac12}\right\|$

holds for all unitarily-invariant norms $\|\cdot\|$.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: One possible approach is to apply Bourin's matrix Chebyshev inequality (see Theorem 1.1 in [arXiv:math/0601543](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601543)):
Let $A,B\geq 0$, and let $Z$ be normal. If $(A,B)$ is monotone, then
$\left\|Z A B \right\|_F \geq  \left\|A Z B\right\|_F$.
Here, the pair $(A,B)$ is monotone if there exits a Hermitian matrix $C$ and two non-decreasing functions $f$ and $g$ such that $A = f(C)$ and $B = g(C)$.
However, in our case the matrices $A$ and $B$ may even not commute. So it is not clear how to apply Bourin's result.

Comment: I'd suggest that you post this interesting question on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions, including the mention that you have posted it here (including the link to here) without getting any reply, and also including your comment right in the question.